# fread failing to read a file

Tags: c, struct, fread

I have a nest struct here.

```
typedef struct 
{
    struct_one    one;  
    struct_two    two;
    struct_three  three;
} outermost_struct;
```

Passing a pointer to the outer struct in the function

```
outermost_struct settings
readFileInStruct(settings_file, &settings)
```

My Function to read the bin file in struct

```
int readConfigIn2Struct
(
    char file_name[],
    outermost_struct*settings_mem_location
)
{
    FILE *ptr_file;
    ptr_file = fopen(file_name,"rb");
    if(ptr_file == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    fread(&(*settings_mem_location),sizeof(outermost_struct),1,ptr_file);
    fclose(ptr_file);
    return 0;
}
```

Here fread fails and returns to the main function. Can anyone tell me why is my fread failing? The size of teh file is 73kb and struct has enough memory to accommodate the entire file.

Now instead of doing fread once for the entire file, I am trying to do fread for each struct. 
    fread(&(*settings_mem_location),sizeof(struct_one),1,ptr_file);

Here fread correctly writes into struct_one. Now I need fread to write into struct_two. How do I advance the pointer to point to struct_two?

Comment: What does "nested struct" mean? You can [edit] your question and add the definition of `defined_nested_struct` to clarify.

Comment: The answer is: Probably yes. Still you show us much to few facts, to be sure.

Comment: How does it fail ? Is `struct_mem_location` allocated ? Is the file open ? `&(*a)` makes as much sense as `(a+1)-1`.

Comment: How do you know what fread did when you aren't looking at the return value?

Comment: @stark I tried using the return value. fread never returns, the program just goes back to main, so I never have a return value from fread

Comment: So the `fopen` is failing.

Comment: @stark fopen opens the file correctly. My code reaches the breakpoint at fread line.

Comment: You can try switching the parameters to `fread`: `sizeof(outermost_struct)` and `1`. This will tell you how many bytes it read successfully. Then compare it to the number of bytes you wanted. This may give you a clue about what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Detailed error checking and logging is debugging for free.  On top of this including additional logging mostly helps.

Below a possible version of the code you show, reflecting my statements above:

```
int readConfigIn2Struct (
  char file_name[],
  outermost_struct * settings_mem_location)
{
#ifdef DEBUG      
  fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d - Entering %s with file_name = '%s', outermost_struct * = %p\n",
    __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, file_name, (void*) settings_mem_location);
#endif

  assert(NULL != file_name);
  assert(NULL != settings_mem_location);

  int result = 0; /* be optimistic. */

  FILE *ptr_file = fopen(file_name, "rb");
  if (ptr_file == NULL)
  {
    result = -1;
  }
  else
  {
    size_t bytes_to_read = sizeof * settings_mem_location;
#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "Bytes to read from '%s': %zu\", file_name, bytes_to_read);
#endif
    size_t bytes_read = fread(settings_mem_location, 1, bytes_to_read, ptr_file);

    if (bytes_read < bytes_to_read)
    {
      result = -1;

      if (feof(ptr_file))
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unexpectedly reached EOF after %zu bytes\", bytes_read);
      }
      else if (ferror(ptr_file))
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "An error occurred after reading %zu bytes\", bytes_read);
      }
    }

    fclose(ptr_file);
  }

#ifdef DEBUG
  fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d - Leaving %s with result = %d\n", __FILE__, 
    __LINE__, __func__, result);
#endif

  return result; /* One exit point per function is preferred over several. */
}
```

Compile with option `-DDEBUG` to enable additional logging like entry and exit.

To have the calls to `assert()` being removed automagically compile with option `-DNDEBUG`.

[Details about `assert()` are in the documentation here.](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Consistency-Checking.html)